# How to apply ATPVBAEN into a dataset with skipped data within the same column?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a problem where I am stuck and cannot figure out a way to solve it.  My code is explained ahead, but the main issue is that I must apply a smoothening exponential function with ATPVBAEN, by sections, because data is not always present, although my x axis still needs to be progressive for each measurement and some may be skipped, as displayed below:
0 34.5
2 40.6
4 41.5
6
8
10 30.4
12 32.9
Since I need to use exponential smoothening in a set of data, so programmatically I accessed in the following form the ATPVBAEN add-in provided by Excel.
Preparing my data:

```
Dim plan As Worksheet
    Set plan = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PLANILLA")
    Dim plan2 As Worksheet
    Set plan2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILTER")
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
```

Getting offsets and coping values to be extracted from original data before using he exponential smoothening.

```
k = data.Range("C2", data.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 'Find last index x axis column
p = k + 15 'Set offset
plan2.Range("K16", "K" & p).Value = data.Range("E2", "E" & k + 1).Value 'Copy values
plan2.Range("L16", "L" & p).Value = data.Range("E2", "E" & k + 1).Value 
plan2.Range("M16", "M" & p).Value = data.Range("F2", "F" & k + 1).Value
```

Now, I run the function that allows me to do the data smoothening, placing data in the row L (destination), using the data from column D (origin). So finally I do the following:

```
 Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Expon", plan2.Range("L16", "L" & p), plan2.Range("D16", "D" & p), smoothVal, False, False, False
```

Here is where I need a way in which I can apply the function in sections, because I have data that skips some cells, leaving them empty. The problem is that Excel assumes empty data as a 0, and my measurements get affected in a really bad way. Is there a work around to apply the ATPVBAEN by parts like in a for loop (setting on each loop the beginning and end with the variables p and k like above)?  How can I be able to recognize where the beginning and end of each subset of data is located within the column? 
Because the line :

```
(…, data.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

seems to be not an effective solution.

My code works greatly when I use the full length of the column with a continuous dataset, but I would like to make it possible to work with datasets that have skipped data.
Many thanks!!

Comment: The data displayed earlier, shows the following: x axis 0-12 meassurements the second row. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is it possible to run `ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Expon` by passing an array instead of a range? Then you could first pass the range into an array, resize the array and eliminate all zeros and then forward those arrays to the macro that you have. BTW, do you merely want to eliminate all the zeros from column D or from Column L or if both / either is zero?

Comment: Yes, I could try to call the macro with an array instead. Zeros could be inserted into empty cells, and then ignore them when taking the array from the column... That would be a good approach, I will try to code it and I will let you know the result

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution and a way to work around is the following:
Use a Loop to iterate over data until we know there are not any subsets left. Skip the subsets doing a module operation to get the reminder og the interation count.

```
Do While reachMax > k 'Control how many times I can iterate over data

        init = prev = k
        counter = counter + 1

    k = data.Range("E" & 1, data.Range("E" & init).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 'Find last index of column
    p = k + 15 'Set offset because we are working with data of other sheet

        If (counter Mod 2) = 1 Then 'Able to skip subsets with no data
         Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Expon", plan2.Range("K" & prev + 14, "K" & p), plan2.Range("C" & prev + 14, "C" & p), smoothVal, False, False, False
        End If

Loop
```

Obviously we are setting the variables of reachMax with the x axis last data, and k with the index number of the y-axis data, in this located in columns C (destination) and K (origin)